Could the voices experienced by individuals with schizophrenia genuinely possess self-awareness?
We lack a precise definition or physical model of self-awareness, but all humans seem to grasp it intuitively—we experience colors, pain, and other subjective qualia. Now consider a person diagnosed with schizophrenia who reports hearing voices in their head that, by some accounts, appear to “live a life of their own.” Is it conceivable that these voices could truly possess their own self-awareness? In other words, alongside the main personality (which we assume has its own self-awareness), might the voices themselves also have a genuine capacity to feel or experience, rather than simply imitating consciousness?

Secondary personalities with awareness would probably classify as dissociative identity disorder (which is the subject of some controversy), rather than schizophrenia. But this distinction and analysis would really be the domain of psychology, not philosophy. All we'd be likely to do here is speculate.

(1) Do you want to know about voices heard by schizophrenics? Or about what's going on with people with multiple personality disorder? (2) A "voice" doesn't "posses" anything, so what is the question? Whether the voice expresses a different personality? It's pretty clear it may do so (it may appear so to the person hearing the voice). So, what is really your question? Perhaps your question is really about how "dissociation" could be or should be or is defined? -- I agree mostly with @NotThatGuy. Haven't voted to close yet, but all this leaves the question on shaky ground.

The psychology would inform the philosophy. As such, answers about DID and schizotypal personalities would be better addressed in Psychology SE. I presume the DSM operationalizes both thorougly, and this a much better Psychology SE question. But it marginally seems fair game as philosoohy of psychology.

The philosophical question might be: What (if any) are the gaps in psychological accounts? And also, given different forms of "dissociation", what kind of "dissociation" justifies talk of a different "personality" or a different "mind". Or - is it justified for "normal" people to see themselves as "one" person? Why? If so, what makes this so? When and how does it break down? -- All those questions seem borderline philosophical/psychological.

@JD - The DSM has imo lots of issues in regards to methodology and the foundations of its taxonomy. I wouldn't assume that the splits (!) in different classes are always thorougly operationalized or justified. (Though in this case, I do assume that.)

I’m voting to close this question because it should be first clarified and made precise - what does it mean that a voice heart by a schizophrenic person is self aware? -  and then posed in a a blog on psychology.

@mudskipper lol I saw the opening and presumed you were Dcleve. Given the history of development, I make no warranty as to its taxonomy personally. Just that given the DSM and the local born-again Christian's take on philosophy of mind, I tend to opt for the former. I have first-hand knowledge of the personal failings of psychology and psychologists (mostly stemming from their, as my anecdotes support, complete and utter ignorance of the philosopohy of mind).

This is likely to be closed because in a naturalized epistemology, many thinkers simply throw certain questions over a non-existent fence in an effort to divide labor. Certainly, there is a philosophical basis of the question as to whether a person can have more than one locus of awareness. Certainly in theology, if possession is admitted, for instance, then sure, two aware beings can inhabit one body.
There is no a priori reason I can cite to claim that two minds cannot occupy one body, though a posteriori evidence seems scant. As was pointed out, exotic cases documented by psychologists do offer some tentative evidence that the human body and brain may be able to assume multiple identities who are in some sense partitioned from each other as in the putative condition known as DID. From WP:

Dissociative identity disorder is characterized by the presence of at least two distinct and relatively enduring personality states. The disorder is accompanied by memory gaps more severe than could be explained by ordinary forgetfulness.

If you accept the operational basis of this diagnosis, and are willing to ontologically commit to the disorder, then it would seem yes, not only can a person have two aware minds, but that those minds have been validated by psychologists, which carries some evidential
weight. From a naturalized epistemology that holds that science is continuous with philosophy, a philosopher (Dennett would be the sort) could certainly offer an explanation of it alongside a psychologist (and probably do so in a more articulate fashion given that philosophy of mind is no small matter). You might be interested in the work of Oliver Sacks who looked at surprising pathological states of mind.

let's apply a little Occam's Razor, shall we? We have a perfectly good, albeit imperfectly understood, material explanation for the phenomenon of schizophrenia: a complex interplay of genetic predispositions, neurochemical imbalances, and environmental factors. These conspire to produce a range of symptoms, including auditory hallucinations, which we colloquially refer to as 'voices.' To suggest that these voices are somehow independent, sentient entities is to introduce a gratuitous metaphysical element where none is required. It's akin to claiming that the static on a poorly tuned radio is broadcasting messages from another dimension, rather than simply being the result of interference.
We know that damage to certain areas of the brain can produce profound changes in personality, memory, and even the sense of self. Are we to believe that these changes somehow conjure up entirely new, independent consciousnesses? It's far more parsimonious to conclude that these experiences, however vivid and compelling they may be to the individual, are the product of a malfunctioning organ, not the irruption of some ghostly other.
